# Add text / label to each point / circle in nvd3 scatter plot?

Tags: d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I've followed the nvd3 scatter plot example to create a scatter plot: http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html

What i'd like to do is display the "size" property (from the data) beneath each circle. I've been trying various combinations of trying to selectAll of the "g.nv-group" elements and then appending "text", but nothing is working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279908/appending-text-to-points-in-angular-nvd3
You may make sure of the code snippet here. Change `d3.select(d).data()[0][1]` to what you want to display, say `size`.

Answer (score 1):

If the data has a label property and

```
chart.showLabels(true)
```

then [this discussion](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/1745) on a closed (not merged) PR suggests it should work. Works on lineCharts.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked code from the link from the comment above, in my case, this worked

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-group path")[0].forEach(function(d){
      var tf = d3.select(d).attr("transform")
      t = d3.transform(tf).translate;
      t[0] = t[0] +10;//moving the translate x by 5 pixel.
      console.log(d3.select(d).data()[0])//data associated with the point
      d3.select(d.parentNode)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text("data: "+ d3.select(d).data()[0][0].size)//putting data
        .attr("transform", "translate("+t[0]+","+t[1]+")");
});
```